# How to run java jars on nginx server locally?

Tags: java, nginx, jar, nginx-config

I pretty new to Nginx and I want to run some java jars on Nginx server in my local machine. How can I achieve this?

I have downloaded nginx for windows from http://nginx.org/en/download.html 
My Nginx version : 1.16.1
My java jars are in the folder - E:\myapp 
How do I point my java jars location in my Nginx server config?

My Nginx Server config is as below (nginx.conf)

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       3000;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            alias E:\myapp
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Nginx is a HTTP server. It can't run Jar files (or any Java code).

Comment: @Kayaman, I have one maven project which generates some multiple jars when the project is built, I need to run these jars on Nginx server. I see some nginx.conf file in the docker folder of my project but I don't know what config i need to change in that nginx.config file to run it in my local machine

Answer (score 3):

You cannot deploy `jar` or `war` on NGINX. Because NGINX is a web server, not a servlet container. 
However, you can deploy the application behind NGINX webserver (on `Jetty` or `tomcat`)

Open `/etc/ngnix/sites-available/default` and provide the routing configuration.

```
location /order-service {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
location /payment-service {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
}
```

Here, `http://localhost/order-service/` will be directed to `http://localhost:8080/`, and requests coming to `http://localhost/payment-service/` will be directed to `http://localhost:9000/`.

**NGINX as a load-balancer**

NGINX can also be used for load balancing running instances.
Here are the steps:

Open `/etc/ngnix/sites-available/default`

```
// instances of order-service
upstream order_services {
  server localhost:8080;
  server localhost:8081;
  server localhost:8082;
}

location /order-service {
    proxy_pass http://order_services;
}
```